# How to get number of connections to MongoDB when auth=true

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB version 2.4.5

I enabled `auth=true` in `mongodb.conf`, then I cannot use `db.serverStatus()` or `mongostat.exe` to get number of connection to MongoDB. They are defect of MongoDB (`https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4977` and `https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/issues/318` )

My question is: Are there any way to get number of connections to MongoDB if `auth=true`?

Comment: In your 2nd link, it said the issue is resolved in https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/commit/019b9c516bd7a2220a174e3b7540c16651a0c3ae

Comment: Yes, but I see it was fixed for milestone 3.4.x
I test it on 2.4.8 and it still occured

Comment: I see. Consider to upgrade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jira issue you linked ([SERVER-4977](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4977)) is referring to the `mongostat` tool and isn't relevant to whether you can call the `serverStatus` command from your own application code or the `mongo` shell if properly authenticated.

If you have enabled authentication in MongoDB 2.4, the `serverStatus` command requires an authenticated user with the [`clusterAdmin` role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#administrative-roles).

Authentication as at MongoDB 2.4 is enabled at the server level, so once enabled all connections will need to be authenticated using appropriate users & roles.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I added new user **db.addUser( { user: "dbadmin3",  pwd: "dbpasswd3", roles: [ "readWrite", "clusterAdmin" ]  } )** and used this user but the issue still occured.

**> use dbtest
switched to db dbtest
> db.auth("dbadmin3","dbpasswd3")
1
> db.serverStatus()
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }**

Please help to confirm if I missed something. Thanks.

Comment: As per the linked information on the `clusterAdmin` role, you have to grant this on the `admin` database (and authenticate against `admin` as well). Are you definitely authenticating against `admin`?

Comment: Many thank you Stennie. It's work.
I create a new user with role `clusterAdmin ` on database `admin`.
Then I connect to `admin` db and execute `db.serverStatus()`. It work.
Thanks.